# How to Force IIS to use HTTP and not HTTPS

Tags: http, iis, https

I'm working on a mobile website and testing it on an Android device with the latest version and the Chrome built in browser.

I originally had a binding for HTTP and HTTPS.  I have removed the HTTPS binding but whenever I attempt to navigate to the site it still switches from `http://` to `https://`.

I've tried clearing the cache on my browsers on my mobile devices and this makes no difference.

I can navigate to the `http://` version on my desktop just fine.

How do I force IIS to only use HTTP and not HTTPS?

Comment: Do you have the URL Rewrite module installed on IIS which has a HTTP > HTTPS redirect rule on it? Does the page load when you get redirected or do you get a 404?

Comment: @haxtbh I don't have the rewrite module installed.  I wonder if this is a solution?

Comment: Well if there is no rule and no binding then the other thing would be that there is something on the actual page that is redirecting to https. Do you do any form or redirect in the website code?